# Draw vertical line on Signal or Entry Command?

Tags: signals, line, pine-script

Trying to add the a vertical line on signal or strategy.entry command.
Better on calibEntry

```
// Figure out take profit price

calibEntry = close - (close * prforentry)
longExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)
shortExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)



//Strategy Long Entry
if ls
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long, limit = calibEntry)
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Tried everything nothing working.